# Cypress test get failed while running from command line, but passing if running from cypress test runner

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to perform a search for places in a search text field. While typing the place name, the system will display autocomplete of the places under the search field. I have written the test using trigger `mousedown` in cypress to grab the autocomplete items.

```
 describe('Search for places', function() {
 it.only('Verify the search is working fine', function() {  
 cy.visit('url')
 cy.get('#search-button').click();
 cy.get('input[type="text"]').type("Salis");
 //cy.get('input[placeholder="Start typing a suburb, city, station or uni"]').parents('.form-container').find('div').find('div').find('input').type("Salis");
 cy.contains('span', 'bury, Brisbane').click();
 //cy.get('.input-autocomplete').find('div.row').eq(0).click(); 
 cy.get('div:contains(" Flatmates")').parents('.search-modes').find('div').find('div').contains(" Flatmates").click();
 cy.get('a:contains("+ Advanced filters")').parents('.show-advanced-wrapper').find('p').find('a').click();
 cy.get('#search-submit > div').contains("Search Flatmates").click();
 cy.get('.section-heading > div > h1').invoke('text').then((text)=>{
    const stext = text;
    expect(stext).to.equal('Salisbury Housemates & Roommates');
 })
  Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    // returning false here prevents Cypress from
    // failing the test
   return false
    })
  })

 })
```

The test runs successfully in Cypress test runner (UI). But while running from the command line, it throws `CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '.input-autocomplete'`, but never found it.

While inspecting the html of the autocomplete item, it disappears the autocomplete items, so unable to get the correct`html` tags. Any idea what could be the reason for that error? Or any other stable way to get the autocomplete items.

[image]

[image]

Added the `html` where cypress test fails while running from command line, see the screen shot below highlighted in red

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you send html from moment of assertion fail?

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak : Added the screenshot where the cypress test fails

Comment: Please share the complete test, screenshots are useful but not enough to try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker Full test added, please have a look

Comment: Cheers, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain the difference between the results from cypress:open and cypress:run (at a guess it's memory related), but there's a few things wrong with the bit of the test you have shown.

First off, show the whole test not just one line - you make it really hard to help by showing fragmentary code.

`.trigger('mousedown',{ which: 1 })`  followed by `.click()` is redundant. Use one method or the other. `click()` is much better for selecting from a list.

Given the latest info, I would go for clicking the specific text content, assuming that the autocomplete list always comes up with the same suggestion for entry of 'Salis'.

```js
cy.get('input').type('Salis');  // How do you type 'Salis'?
cy.contains('span', 'bury, Brisbane').click();
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I have tried both ways, `cy.get('form').find('div.row').eq(0).click(); ` and `cy.get('.input-autocomplete').find('div.row').eq(0).click();` boh getting failed while running from `command line`. But the test is passing while running in test runner UI

Comment: I have added one more screenshot to the question, the last with expanded `span ` tags

Comment: As you may aware of the behavior of autocomplete,  When you type in the search field, the autocomplete items displays, the moment you took the mouse control, the autocomplete list disappears. So is it due to this the tests get failed in cypress while running from command line?

Comment: That was why I suggest you should not use `trigger` - all you want to do is `click` and I think the page will not change if you use click by itself.

Comment: The command line problem may be due to that, or maybe some subtle bug in Cypress (or a difference in runtime condition like memory which is going to be difficult to pin down). Best to try a few different test patterns and see if one works with the command line.

Comment: ok, as suggested I have used click and tried with `cy.contains('span', 'bury, Brisbane').click();` but fails CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'bury, Brisbane' within the selector: 'span' but never did.

Comment: I know that's not the same exact issue but remember that the Cypress's mouse events management isn't perfect, take a look at this issue I raised from another user error https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2521